# Bootstrap modals in Angular2

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular, bootstrap-modal

I'm using Angular2 and bootstrap for my web application.

I use a lot of bootstrap dialogs and I noticed that the only way to make them works great is to put them as last children of the **body** tag.

But how can I do this using angular2 and without third party libs (all the libs I found have no support)?

I created this wrapper:

```
export abstract class BaseDialogComponent<TArgument, TResult> implements OnDestroy
{
    @Input() id:number;
    @Input() openDialogEvent:EventEmitter<TArgument>;
    @Output() closeEvent:EventEmitter<TResult> = new EventEmitter<TResult> ();

    public argument:TArgument = <any>{};
    private openDialogEventSubscription:EventSubscription;

    public constructor ()
    {
        setTimeout (() => {
            this.openDialogEventSubscription = this.openDialogEvent.subscribe (arg => {
                this.argument = arg;
                this.onDialogReady ();

                jQuery('#' + this.id).modal();
            });
        });
    }

    public ngOnDestroy ()
    {
        if (this.openDialogEventSubscription)
            this.openDialogEventSubscription.unsubscribe ();
    }

    protected abstract onDialogReady ():void;

    protected onCloseClick ()
    {
        this.closeDialog (undefined);
    }

    protected closeDialog (result:TResult)
    {           
        jQuery('#' + this.id).modal ("hide");

        if (result !== undefined)
            this.closeEvent.emit (result);
    }
}
```

And you can use it like this:

```
@Component({
    moduleId : module.id,
    selector: 'my-selector',
    templateUrl: 'my-template.component.html',
})
export class CompanyDetailsDialogComponent extends BaseDialogComponent<string, void> 
{     
    protected onDialogReady ():void 
    {
        alert ('hello ' + this.argument);
    }
}
```

It is quite confortable to use and works great, but in this way the html code is located inside the component that uses the dialog, and not directly in the **body** tag.

Can you suggest me how to use bootstrap dialog properly in agular2?

Comment: basically you want to create component for the bootstrap modal right ? so that you can easily import and use in the another components ?

Comment: You right! My code already do this, the problem is that the modal html code is nested inside the component that uses the modal and not right inside the body tag

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to consider https://github.com/dougludlow/ng2-bs3-modal ? It works great in our project. And if you should really run into problems, you would be able to fix it yourself without support, since the source code is quite clear and brief.

Comment: http://shlomiassaf.github.io/angular2-modal/ does what you want.
The source code is available so you can see how it's done.

To set the element as the last child of root you need to create it manually via ComponentResolver and Factory, then append the result to document.body

Comment: @user3471528 see here `Delete Modal` component seems same case as you want may help you, https://github.com/MrPardeep/Angular2-DatePicker#live-demo ,  if you get your answer ill post it as answer may help someone else,